# How to get max of sound quality for music listening?

Tags: audio, music, headphones

Yo,
I like to listen to music through headphones, so I'd like to tweak the sound parameters on my phone and tablet to my taste.

What can be done in this direction? My devices are not rooted.

Comment: What kind of parameters are you trying to tweak? It's not as simple as setting `sound_good=true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound purely depends on phone make and model and the headsets too. Most of the phones support 5-band custom Equalizer (you can tweak them just like that) and some phones only support the given presets like Bass, Flat, Treble , 5.1 Channel etc. Sony phones have their own technology like xLoud and ClearBass. So it depends on various things. Also you can download music players from Play Store if the stock music player doesn't support all these options.
Try all of these and pick the best **as you've not mentioned your phone and tablet model and are not rooted.**

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous Equalizer Apps on the Play Store for those who haven't got root access.
If you want to manipulate / enhance your sound quality even more there are a lot of improvements for rooted devices.

I know that [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/) has some features especially for music enthusiasts. i.e a very customizable Equalizer.
Having the root access which comes with CM you can also install MOD's like the [ACID](http://blooglog.blogspot.ch/2013/02/acid-audio-engine-mod-to-improve-sound.html) audio engine which is said to improve audio quality significantly, especially when listening with headphones.

FYI: the [CyanogenMod Installer](http://beta.download.cyanogenmod.org/install) is back which allows you to install it without having much knowledge of rooting devices.